# "Flattening" output of group.nth in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My indexing skills are not quite up to par and I'm struggling with this problem.

I have the following setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.bdate_range('2012-1-1', periods=250)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(250,4), index=index, columns=[1, 2, 3, 4])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(250,4), index=index, columns=[1, 2, 3, 4])
df = pd.concat({'A': df1, 'B': df2}, axis=1)

group = df.groupby([lambda x: x.year, lambda x: x.month])
```

I see that the maximum no. of business days within my groups (i.e., (year, month) combinations) is 23:

```
In [257]: group.size().max()
Out[257]: 23
```

And for the 1st business day (index n=0) of every month, I can get statistics as follows:

```
In [258]: group.nth(0).describe()
Out[258]: 
               A                                           B             \
               1          2          3          4          1          2   
count  12.000000  12.000000  12.000000  12.000000  12.000000  12.000000   
mean    0.541559   0.491684   0.354012   0.448284   0.353839   0.408020   
std     0.367662   0.242924   0.254447   0.248426   0.228194   0.220511   
min     0.021792   0.110715   0.067677   0.074719   0.097227   0.116947   
25%     0.144712   0.368966   0.144415   0.209418   0.189507   0.260863   
50%     0.646160   0.439860   0.233370   0.472696   0.214474   0.370281   
75%     0.865417   0.614928   0.587038   0.710450   0.529376   0.602299   
max     0.963938   0.912865   0.766722   0.750037   0.778580   0.776627   


               3          4  
count  12.000000  12.000000  
mean    0.434197   0.588980  
std     0.301113   0.287869  
min     0.004253   0.064859  
25%     0.262517   0.357484  
50%     0.350605   0.653136  
75%     0.676960   0.775588  
max     0.991661   0.990118
```

What I would like to do is run group.nth(n).describe() for n in range(23), and save the results in this format:

```
                 count      mean       std   min   25%   50%   75%   max
(col2, n, col1)    281 -0.004093  0.140578 -1.64 -0.04 -0.00  0.04  0.58
```

For all combinations of (col2, n, col1) where col2 is the lower column name (1 through 4), n is in range(23), and col1 is the upper column name ('A' or 'B').

Any help would be greatly appreciated -- I'll learn a lot about how to do these kinds of manipulations.  I got some of the way there with:

```
group.nth(0).describe().stack().T.stack()`
```

But I make a hash of it when I iterate n through 22.

Thank you.

Comment: so you want to end up with a "concatted" dataframe of basically the transposed versions of group.nth(n).describe()?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for.  I need to develop a better feel for stack and unstack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. You just need to use the index to generate an explicit list from index to put the `n` in the middle. Then, with the list of dataframes, you can just use `concat` straight up.

```
group = df.groupby([lambda x: x.year, lambda x: x.month])
dataframes = []
for n in range(23):
    frame = group.nth(n).describe().T
    frame.index = [(inner, n, outer) for outer, inner in frame.index]
    dataframes.append(frame)
final_df = pd.concat(dataframes)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff!  Don't stack().unstack() negate each other?  I ended up getting what I needed using just describe().T and your n loop.

Comment: @user2461398 True. I guess I started off of what you had and played around until I had what I wanted.