# Pandas: flattening repeating/wrapped columns in csv file

Tags: csv, pandas

It often happens that data will be given to you with wrapped columns. Consider, for example:

```
    CCY  Decimals      CCY    Decimals      CCY    Decimals
AUD/CAD         5  EUR/CZK           4  GBP/NOK           5
AUD/CHF         5  EUR/DKK           5  GBP/NZD           5
AUD/DKK         5  EUR/GBP           5  GBP/PLN           5
AUD/JPY         3  EUR/HKD           5  GBP/SEK           5
AUD/NOK         5  EUR/HUF           3  GBP/SGD           5
...
```

Which should be parsed as a dataframe of *two* columns (CCY and Decimals), not six. My question is, what is the most idiomatic way of achieving this?

I would have wanted something like the following:

```
data = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
data.groupby(axis=1,by=data.columns.map(lambda s: s.replace("\..",""))).\
    apply(lambda df : df.values.flatten())
```

When reading the csv file we end up with columns `CCY`,`Decimals`,`CCY.1`,`Decimals.1` .. etc. The `groupby` operation returns a collection of data frames:

```
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x3a52b10>
```

Which we would then flatten using numpy functionality. So we would are converting DataFrames with repeating columns into Series, and then merging these into a result DF.

However, this doesn't work. I've tried passing the different `keys` arguments to `groupBy`, but it always complains about being unable to reindex non-unique columns.

There are a number of existing questions that deal with flattening groups of columns (e.g. ["Flattening" output of group.nth in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975933/flattening-output-of-group-nth-in-pandas)), but I can't find any that do this for repeating columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `groupby`, I'd do:

```
>>> groups = df.groupby(axis=1,by=lambda x: x.rsplit(".",1)[0])
>>> pd.DataFrame({k: v.values.flat for k,v in groups})
        CCY  Decimals
0   AUD/CAD         5
1   EUR/CZK         4
2   GBP/NOK         5
3   AUD/CHF         5
4   EUR/DKK         5
5   GBP/NZD         5
6   AUD/DKK         5
7   EUR/GBP         5
8   GBP/PLN         5
9   AUD/JPY         3
10  EUR/HKD         5
11  GBP/SEK         5
12  AUD/NOK         5
13  EUR/HUF         3
14  GBP/SGD         5

[15 rows x 2 columns]
```

and then sort.